# How to implement application layer behaviour in ns-2 using Tcl

Tags: tcl, snmp, ns2, otcl

Clumsy title, apologies.

I'm quite new to ns-2, well by that I mean I can create simulations fine as long as I don't need to do anything outside of the core functionality.

I want to make a very simple SNMP model (as there is no SNMP model that I can find for ns-2), that is literally a case of 1 node polling all other nodes on a subnet, and the other nodes responding. This will happen every n seconds according to the polling rate.

It's easy enough to set up a CBR UDP agent with an interval parameter to model the polling, but what is the best way to get the other nodes to respond upon receiving a packet? Or is this even the best way to do it?

I ask this not in the spirit of expecting someone to plaster a massive C++ script here to help me, but because from what I can find by googling, it's hinted that this sort of thing should be quite straightforward using the Tcl interface.

Does anyone have the faintest idea what I'm on about and if so any useful pointers?

Thanks alot,
Duncan